# AngularJS ng-repeat : filter: $variable doesn't work well when using 'true' for strict comparison

Tags: angularjs, json, limit, repeat

I receive a JSON file of Stores, with id, name, among other data.
I have a view called List, and other called Detail.

In List, I list all the JSON with ng-repeat.
In Detail, I have the 'same' list, but ng-repeat I use filter by id like:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in spots | filter:{id: idSpot}">
{{item.id}} - {{item.name}}
...
```

But the problem I've encountered is that when I filter the business id: 3, it shows, all the businesses with a number 3 (3, 30, 73, 33, ...).

I've found also that the **true** element, forces to make the comparison strictly to the received value:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in spots | filter:{id: idSpot}:true">
```

Works perfect, when I write  "filter:{id: 7}:true", equal to seven.

But it does NOT work when I compare it like it is written, {id: idSpot}

$scope.idSpot is properly set at the Controller, and I know it works, because it showed all the three's (3, 33, 73, 39,...) before. 
I can console.log($scope.idSpot) and confirm it receives an integer.

But the variable doesn't work with 'true'.

How could I polish that??

Thank you!

Comment: Does your detail list always only contain one Object?

Comment: Both views share the same Controller, Detail-view has the whole Object, with 90 stores. It works perfect when the {{ item.id }} is unique (eg: 70, 21, ), but fails when filtering a single digit (7 is part of 7, or 17 or.. 71.. ). Non-strict comparison. :/

Comment: id recommend including a pen/fiddle.

Comment: Here's working partially. The second example with :true, does not do the same effect, to show only one:

http://jsfiddle.net/ButterySAM777/8n8e5qu3/2/

Comment: what version of angular do you use? i saw in the fiddle that it uses a old version. I updated the version and a bit of the Syntax and now everything works as expected.. see http://jsfiddle.net/Lddh7ju3/

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.4.3, as it's part of a PhoneGap Framework application.
I will try updating the version to the 1.6 then. =)

Comment: Damn' it works, and to think I've been struggling a couple of days with that. Thank you Founded1898!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, as I had a lot of time to think, I've found a patch to carry on from.

As this code:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in spots | filter:{id: idSpot}">
{{item.id}} - {{item.name}}
</div>
```

When receive a one-digit number, like 3; it printed all numbes with a 3 (13, 31, 33,34,...), I will add the ng-if clause, to take $index == 0, that is the first lowest result returned. The #3.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in spots | filter:{id: idSpot}" ng-if="$index == 0">
```

Didn't correct the Filter though. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I had an Eureka-Moment and came up to my mind why it failled to me this filtering, maybe some lost-soul will find this post and have another idea to consider.

When I had this:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in spots | filter:{id: idSpot}:true">
```

$scope.idSpot is a variable that gets initialised when receiving one item from the list, therefore I send the {id} from the JSON object to this variable.

But what I had was NOT an integer. '3' was a String, so it failled when I forced the comparison to (id == 3), because I was comparing a Character with a Number. 
Here my mistake.

I came right away to test it, and I was right.
Thank you again!